# visual studio 2010 installer in romanian

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, translation

I want to create a Visual Studio 2010 installer in Romanian lanaguage but I don't know how to do that.

I've created in `C:\ProgramFiles\MsVS10.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment\VsdDialogs` a new folder `1048` for Romanian language and I've modified some string with `Orca`.

Then I tried to modify the registry:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWEARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Deployment\DialogTemplates`

And put `Languages-> Romanian`, `Identifiers 1048` and `CodePages 1250`.

Now Romanian language appears in the drop down in `VS2010->Setup->Localization` but I can't select it.

What to do?

Or any other solution on how to create a VS2010 installer in a language that is not present in the Setup->Localization.

Many thanks.